# General LIMIT and ORDER BY in Union

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:
`SELECT pr.ONE FROM prec pr WHERE ... ORDER BY pr.time_of_insertion DESC LIMIT 10) UNION (SELECT hr.TWO FROM hrec hr WHERE ... ORDER BY hr.time_of_insertion DESC LIMIT 10)`

Both the tables have one field name in common, although unrelated between them, which is **time_of_insertion**. What I'd like to do perform the query to retrieve Limit X **that should apply to ALL union** (X rows in total, not Y+Y from each query) **and the criteria should be ORDER BY time_of_insertion DESC that applies to BOTH tables**. I hope I made me through. How can I perform this? Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) explains how to achieve both your goals:

> However, use of `ORDER BY` for individual `SELECT` statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because `UNION` by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of `ORDER BY` in this context is typically in conjunction with LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the `SELECT`, even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final `UNION` result. If `ORDER BY` appears without `LIMIT` in a `SELECT`, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway.
>
> To use an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause to sort or limit the entire `UNION` result, parenthesize the individual `SELECT` statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one.

In plain English, you can `ORDER BY time_of_insertion DESC`. All you have to do is to add it to the end of your query, outside the parentheses (at the same level as `UNION`) **and** also make the value available at the `UNION` level, i.e. put `time_on_insertion` into both `SELECT`s.

Regarding the `LIMIT 10`, you can also get it the same way: put `LIMIT 10` after the `ORDER BY` placed before.

The query:

```
(
    SELECT pr.ONE, pr.time_of_insertion
    FROM prec pr
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY pr.time_of_insertion DESC
    LIMIT 10
)
UNION
(
    SELECT hr.TWO, hr.time_of_insertion
    FROM hrec hr
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY hr.time_of_insertion DESC
    LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY time_of_insertion DESC
LIMIT 10
```